# How to match exactly words in list

Tags: regex

I have the issue when trying to use Regex to catch some words.

Regexr Link: http://regexr.com/3gfr4

[My Regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCT5X.png)

I use `\b(menu|mes|close|set)\b` to catch menu, mes, close, set. It working fine. But like the image above It catch `menu` in `.@menu`. I don't need catch this word when start with `@`.

I Try to change Regex to `\b^(menu|mes|close|set)\b`. But working incorrect.

Anyone know how to fix this, thank you!

Comment: Do you want to catch them only when surrounded by spaces?

Comment: What is the language? And are you extracting text, or replacing?

Comment: You say "words in list", where is the list? How is the pattern formed? What is your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only expect these words to be at the start of the line then what you changed it to is correct. WHat you are missing is the m (multiline) flag

```
/^\b(menu|mes|close|set)\b/gm
```

http://regexr.com/3gfr7

Answer (score 0):

1) Alter your string with spaces around:

```
$str = " $str ";
```

2) Change regex to:

```
\s(menu|mes|close|set)\s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only word surrounded by spaces or at beginng or end of string:

```
(?:^|\s)(menu|mes|close|set)(?:\s|$)
```